# Populating a TableView in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hey guys I am having an issue passing a JSON return type through an `NSArray`

`.h` file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *finishedGooglePlacesArray;
```

`.m` file:

Here is the returned section:

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:returnData //1

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = [json objectForKey:@"original_request"];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Now from there it gets sent to here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

    if([tempDictionary objectForKey:@"location"] != NULL)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rating: %@ of 5",[tempDictionary   objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not Rated"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

But it breaks on

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

with an error message:

```
2014-03-08 13:53:26.772 Ripple[45593:70b] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b72810
2014-03-08 13:53:26.776 Ripple[45593:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b72810'
```

I am not sure what is going on, suggestions or thoughts?

edit:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking count];
}
```

JSON

```
responseString: {"status":"ok","code":0,"message":"Testing this awesome application out!","from":"Admin Team","original_request":{"name":"david","location":"awesome","trait":"funny"}}
```

Update:

Screen shot of error:
[image: error]

Comment: put the log of json here . that will help.

Comment: You expect an array but you actually have a dictionary. Log the JSON and check what is in `original_request` to see how you need to change the drill into the data.

Comment: Please show your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method as well.

Comment: Okay I made an update, please check

Comment: original_request isn't array, it's a dictionary.

Comment: @mustafabesnili if I changed it to `NSArray* check = [json objectForKey:@"original_request"];
    self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = check;` I would still get an error on the `NSDictionary`

Comment: [json objectForKey:@"original_request"] returns an NSDictionary that you're trying to put in NSArray. You need to change type  googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking to NSDictionary.

Comment: I've done that but it still does not go I get an: `erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b6a1a0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JSON log, `[json objectForKey:@"original_request"] returns an`NSDictionary`. So First you need to change this line :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking;
```

to

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking;
```

It's normal that you get an error after that because `NSDictionary` doesn't have `objectAtIndex` selector. You can enumerate through keys and values in `NSDictionary`.

Than, change your cellForRowAtIndexPath method to :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectForKey:@"name"];

    if([self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectForKey:@"location"] != NULL)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rating: %@ of 5",[self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not Rated"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the response! shouldnt `tempDictionary` be changes to `NSDictionary`?

Comment: You don't need to declare another NSDictionary, so i didn't use it.

Comment: What is temptDictionary than?

Comment: You just delete it. You don't need to use it.

Comment: Okay so than why do I need the tempDictionary? It would only cause my code to fail.

Comment: you're absolutely right, copy paste mistake :), i edited my code.

Comment: Oh I see you meant for me to delete that totally, haha okay I got it!

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you don't understand what you get from your json...

so, try this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //get the correct type
    NSDictionary *tempDictionary = (NSDictionary *)self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking;

    NSString *key = [[tempDictionary allKeys]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = key;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:key];

    return cell;
}
```